# How to hide/display revolution slider according to standard time Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, slider

I am using revolution slider on one of my WordPress site. I am planning to make the slider change according to the standard time.
Example I have slider1(Morning), slider2(Noon), slider3(Evening) and slider4
(Midnight).

I want revolution slider to read the standard time and change the slide accordingly.

I tried this using JavaScript by giving unique class names for each slider.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
var time = new Date().getHours(); 
if (time >= 8) {
document.getElementsByClassName('morningslide').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementsByClassName('noonslide').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('eveningslide').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('midnightslide').style.visibility='hidden';
}


if (time >= 12) {
document.getElementsByClassName('appBanner').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('noonslide').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementsByClassName('eveningslide').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('midnightslide').style.visibility='hidden';
}


if (time >= 18) {
document.getElementsByClassName('morningslide').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('noonslide').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('eveningslide').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementsByClassName('midnightslide').style.visibility='hidden';
}


if (time >= 22) {
document.getElementsByClassName('morningslide').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('noonslide').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('eveningslide').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('midnightslide').style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection. You are setting they style of the collection, not of the elements themselves. You will have to loop through the collection and set the style of each one individually if they are not unique, or if they are unique you could simply select the first element from the collection using `[0]`. My recommendation though would be to give each element a unique ID and use `document.getElementById()` which will return the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in a sample html page and it works. The only modification I did was to use IDs instead of classes and used 'display' instead of 'visibility'.However, both attributes will work fine. I'm assuming that you are placing this in the footer of the page. Try this code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <div id="morningslide">Hello this is Morning</div>
    <div id="noonslide">Hello this is Noon</div>
    <div id="eveningslide">Hello this is Evening</div>
    <div id="midnightslide">Hello this is Midnight</div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
    var time = new Date().getHours();
    document.getElementById('morningslide').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('noonslide').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('eveningslide').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('midnightslide').style.display='none';

    if (time > 8 && time < 11) {
        document.getElementById('morningslide').style.display='block';
    }
    else if (time >= 12 && time <= 18) {
        document.getElementById('noonslide').style.display='block';
    }
    else if (time > 18 && time <= 22) {
        document.getElementById('eveningslide').style.display='block';
    }
    else if (time > 22) {
        document.getElementById('midnightslide').style.display='block';
    }

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working on html page. but when I use it on my revolution slider custom JavaScript code block. its not working.